# Create custom chapter template in scrbook

Tags: spacing, chapters, koma-script, vertical

I am in the final format alignment of my dissertation with the publisher. Unfortunately, there are some requirements that I need to fulfill but struggle with implementing.

I am using scrbook. In the frontmatter, I have several "chapters" (e.g. foreword, preface) that require special vertical spacing: 5cms from horizontal header line to chapter title. To my understanding I cannot use the 
\redeclaresectioncommand provided by Koma, as this would change the format of all chapters in the document (which I do not want). Hence, I am looking for a way to only change the vertical spacing of few selected chapters by creating a new chapter command, say "introchapter", that is exactly the same as chapter except for the chapterheadstartvskip.

In my MWE, I try to show that the renewcommand for chapterheadstartvskip works for the existing chapter command, but not for my "newly created" introchapter command. Any ideas? Where am I missing something?

I highly appreciate your support!

```
\documentclass[12pt, tocindentauto, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc, final]{scrbook}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{5cm}}

\newcommand*{\introchapter}{\chapter\chapterheadstartvskip{\vspace{5cm}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{oldchapter}

\newpage

\introchapter{newchapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply change the vskip locally:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tocindentauto, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc, final]{scrbook}

\let\orichapterheadstartvskip\chapterheadstartvskip



\begin{document}

\chapter{oldchapter}


\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{5cm}}
\chapter{newchapter}


\let\chapterheadstartvskip\orichapterheadstartvskip
\chapter{oldchapter}

\end{document}
```